# Mean of NDVI rasters across time point in QGIS after removing bad quality pixels

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, raster-calculator, ndvi

I have several NDVI and EVI rasters from different time points across a study period. These are of a region in Burkina Faso, and during the rainy season pixel reliability can be low. I have first masked each raster using the pixel reliability raster so that each NDVI and EVI raster has only the pixels that had a quality score of 0 or 1 (scores are 0, 1 or 3 with 3 being less reliable). I used GRASS r.mask.rast to do this. To get NDVI/EVI across the region I need to combine 6 layers for each index and get the mean values for each pixel.

I have tried to do this using the QGIS raster calculator (my input screenshot 1), cell statistics (my input screenshot 2) and GRASS r.series.accumulate (my input screenshot 3) but I get quite different results for each. The calculator gives me almost no actual pixels back. The cell statistics gives me all the pixels but they look a lot paler (lower values) for the mean than I expected, as does the max value. This might be accurate and I might be being stupid. For the accumulate I get something more like what i would expect with all the pixels, but I do get several warning messages when I run it (the log closes before I can copy them to paste!). All of my rasters are set to ESPG 32630 UTM zone 30N

calculator
[image: 1]
Cell stats
[image: 2]
accumulate
[image: accumulate]

If none of these things is the correct process, is there a better process?

Answer (score 0):

Since you started with GRASS GIS, why not do the whole process in using GRASS? There is a module `r.series` ( [manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.series.html) ) that can calculate any one of several statistics on a pixel-by-pixel basis from a series of rasters. This module also ignores NULL values (which is probably your problem above).

If you have six EVI maps and six quality masks as follows:
`evi_1, evi_2,...evi_6` and `evi_qa_1, evi_qa_2, ... evi_qa_6` then you could try the following loop in the GRASS command shell:

```
# *Always* set computational region at start
g.region -ap rast=evi_1  # assumes all maps are overlapping
# First loop thru all vegetation index maps and prepare the masked maps
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
  # set the mask
  r.mask evi_qa_${i} maskcats=1,2  # only use the values 1,2 for the mask
  # create a new, masked veg index map
  r.mapcalc "evi_masked_${i} = evi_${i}"
  # remove the mask for the next loop 
  r.mask -r
done

# Now build the list of masked veg index maps and then create an averaged series
MAPLIST=`g.list type=raster pattern="evi_masked*" separator=comma`
r.series input=${MAPLIST} output=evi_average method=average
```

HTH

Comment: Hi Micha, thank you very much for this, which I will try. I have one query - I notice that you first set a mask, and then use the calculating function, before removing the mask. How does this compare to when using the tools separately? I.e., I will have to give a step-by-step of this part during one of my group meetings, and it might be handy to know how to do it both through the shell and through the point-and-click avenues. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. When you set a mask in GRASS, all subsequent actions use that mask. So every result for whatever module you use will have values **only** within the mask. Since your quality rasters for the VI data will probably be different each time point, then you need to set the mask, run `r.mapcalc` to get the masked EVI values, then remove the mask to prepare for the next time point.